# Type 'Double' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence Type'

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors, double, syntax-error

This is my code and I don't know why it's not working. The title is what the error says. I'm working with Swift in Xcode and the code is supposed to create a function with as many parameters as I tell it to have/unlimited.

```
func addMyAccountBalances(balances : Double) -> Double {
    var result : Double = 0

    for balance in balances {
        result += balance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> the code is supposed to create a function with as many parameters as i tell it

What you probably want is a function taking a *variable number of arguments*,
this is indicated by `...` following the type:

```
func addMyAccountBalances(balances : Double ...) -> Double {
    var result : Double = 0
    for balance in balances {
        result += balance
    }
    return result
}

print(addMyAccountBalances(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
print(addMyAccountBalances(4.5, 5.6))
```

Inside the function, `balances` has the array type `[Double]` so that
you can iterate over its elements.

Note that this can be written more compactly with `reduce()`:

```
func addMyAccountBalances(balances : Double ...) -> Double {
    let result = balances.reduce(0.0, combine: +)
    return result
}
```

Your code does not compile because `balances : Double` is just
a double number, not an array or sequence.